# angularjs bind with value from server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am creating a table that holds product information.

For each row I have an package field. The system requires that the information for packages is stored on the server as a json file.

What I am trying to do is in the ngRepeat for each row, to query the server and bind the returned value to the td.

I have an array of products that I am using for the table, and the table is created like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="product in products">
    <td>{{product.value}}</td>
    <td>{{product.name}}</td>
    <td>{{getPackageNameById(product.package)}}</td>
</tr>
```

The getPackageNameById function does the request to the server, via a service, and returns the package object

The function:

```
$scope.getPackageNameById = function(packageId){
      Packages.getPackageById(packageId)
      .then(function (components) {
        console.log(components); // THIS WORKS, I SEE THE RETURNED PACKAGE OBJECT
        return components;
      }, function (error) {
        console.error(error);
      });
    };
```

The Service:

```
factory('Packages', function ($q, $http) {
    return {
      getPackageById: function (packageId) {
        var deferred = $q.defer(),
          httpPromise = $http.get('/packages/'+packageId);

        httpPromise.success(function (components) {
          deferred.resolve(components);
        })
          .error(function (error) {
            console.error('Error: ' + error);
          });

        return deferred.promise;
      },
    };
  });
```

The problem is that the getPackageNameById gets in to an infinite loop and the site crashes.

I would very much appreciate any suggestions on how to achieve this in the correct way TIA!

Comment: `getPackageNameById` does _not_ return the package object, it returns nothing (but starts an asynchronous operation). When you call it from an `ng-repeat`, you'll start a lot of requests, one for each row, but these will be executed asynchronously.

Comment: Strikes me this might be better solved on the back end. What if you have hundreds of products? Do you really want your page making all those AJAX requests when a bit of tinkering on the back end could provide you all the data you need in one payload?

Comment: I agree with @net.uk.sweet - you'll be ahead to figure this out on the backend and send one chunk of data back to the browser. Your ng-repeat will be a lot cleaner that way. If you have a list of Package IDs, perhaps you could send your $http request with all of them together, query the data on the server, then return all of the package info together.

Comment: Even if back end requires separate call...you sure don't want that to be generated from the view. View can go through numerous digest cycles causing unneccessary requests for data that may already exist. Make the call from inside original service method that gets all the packages

Comment: thanks for the comments, it makes sense and I will handle this on the server side

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

> `<td>{{getPackageNameById(product.package)}}</td>`

I think Angular two-way data binds doesn't work fine with function call

> `$scope.getPackageNameById()`

Doesn't return value

So, use a property for data bind:

```
<tr ng-repeat="product in products">
    <td>{{product.value}}</td>
    <td>{{product.name}}</td>
    <td>{{product.packageValue.value}}</td>
</tr>
```

Get the information for all products:

```
angular.forEach($scope.products, function(product) {
  product.packageValue = $scope.getPackageNameById(product.package);
});
```

Define a "class" to create new objects references

```
var Package = function(){
    return {
        value: 0
    };
}
```

And, return the value correctly

```
$scope.getPackageNameById = function(packageId){
   var packageValue = new Package();
   Packages.getPackageById(packageId)
   .then(function (components) {
     packageValue.value = components;
   }, function (error) {
     console.error(error);
   });
   return packageValue;
 };
```